# Error deploying Lambda function from Docker container: "--runtime is required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I am attempting to deploy an AWS Lambda function following the basic example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-instructions

I follow the steps exactly up until the "create-function" step:

```
aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name $FUNCTIONNAME \
  --package-type Image \
  --code ImageUri=$URI:latest \
  --role $ROLE_ARN
```

When I attempt to run the above, I get the error "--runtime" is required.

The runtime SHOULD be Python3.11. If I provide that option, I get an error: "--handler is required".

If I specify the handler i.e. "lambda_function.lambda_handler" then I get the error "unrecognized options, --package-type, Image"

According to the docs for create-function:

> If the deployment package is a container image , then you set the package type to Image . For a container image, the code property must include the URI of a container image in the Amazon ECR registry. You do not need to specify the handler and runtime properties.

I can see that the repository exists in ECR and has been updated. Why does create-function not understand that I want to deploy from a container?

Comment: Ensure role URI, function name etc. - that all your variables are resolving. Can you rewrite the query without the variables and hard code the values and try again?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well and same result. All the values like URIs and ARNs have been copy-pasted directly from the AWS Console.

Comment: CLI v1 or v2? `aws —version` output?

Comment: $ aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.147 Python/2.7.18 Linux/5.15.122-77.145.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.18.6

Comment: I should add, I am 90% sure I was able to perform this action, creating a function from a container through the CLI, without issue a week or two ago. But this occurs even when I run the same example I had previously created.